# JSON Property Name Optional

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Using Newtsonsoft JSON, is it possible to use either the `JsonProperty` or the C# Property name when deserializing?  Basically, is there an option I am missing that allows both of the example JSON files below to be deserialized?

**C# Class**

```
public class MyClass 
{
    [JsonProperty("CustomerName")]
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }
}
```

**First JSON File**

```
{
    "ExternalId":"Test1"
}
```

**Second JSON File**

```
{
   "CustomerName":"Test2"
}
```

Comment: Simple solution: add both properties to your class and have them use the same backing field.

Comment: I had considered that but its really ugly (code wise)

Comment: Sometimes ugly is all you have :)

Comment: @DavidG Thank you, your solution did work and I used the SO Question you said is a duplicate as the backing of my solution.  Thank you.